I can't save the data in the database, is there an error in my code?
I try to enter the data, but it's always wrong, where am I going wrong?
// Prepared statement to protect against SQL injections
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename ('address', 'sponsor', 'gold', 'nonce') VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $address);
$stmt->bindParam(2, 1000000);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $ref);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $nonce);



// Prepared statement to protect against SQL injections
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename ('address', 'sponsor', 'gold', 'nonce') VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $address);
$stmt->bindParam(2, 1000000);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $ref);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $nonce);

I try to enter the data, but it's always wrong, where am I going wrong?

Did you execute the $stmt ? --- Please  post a minimal reproducible example

Any errors reported  by MySQL?

Can you change it like below and check?
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $tablename ('address', 'sponsor', 'gold', 'nonce') VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
$stmt->execute();

